# How to insert ISODate(DateTime) to mongodb with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have one class.

I adding class to mongodb.

but DateTime Properties as shows the string

c#

```
public class FRM_FORMREQUEST
{
    public int ORACLE_ID { get; set; }
    public string FORMNUMBER { get; set; }
    public string COMPANYCODE { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RECORDDATE { get; set; }
    public string RECORDUSER { get; set; }
}
```

mongodb record

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56927dfc249d951f1031f526"),
"ORACLE_ID" : 771653,
"FORMNUMBER" : "4992014309217",
"COMPANYCODE" : "499",
"RECORDDATE" : "2014-08-21T19:35:27",
"RECORDUSER" : "parttime35"
}
```

Business

```
 var jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FRM_FORMREQUEST);



 MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonData);


 frmFormCollection.Insert(document);
```

I want  insert like Date

thanks for all help.

Comment: What's the problem? Dates are stored in that way in MongoDB. When you query it from MongoDB using the C# driver, it should serialize as Datetime correctly.

Comment: I can not date query

 FRM_FORMRESPONSE form = frmFormCollection.AsQueryable<FRM_FORMRESPONSE>().Where(l => l.RECORDDATE <= DateTime.Now).FirstOrDefault();

this query is null

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're serializing it to JSON using Json.Net, which will write the dates as strings in the ISO 8601 standard format by default. Then you're de-serializing it to a `BsonDocument` using the BsonSerializer, which (unless you give it any other instructions) will just assume those are strings.

I have to ask, why jump through these hoops? Why not just let the driver serialize your object for you when you call `Insert()`?

```
collection.Insert(FRM_FORMREQUEST);
```

Or, if you have to work with a `BsonDocument`, use the mongo BsonSerializer to convert your object directly (instead of converting it to Json first).

```
var document = FRM_FORMREQUEST.ToBson();
collection.Insert(document);
```

Comment: He may not be jumping through hoops on purpose... my situation is similar... I only have JSON from a client, I have no opportunity to convert a BSON object directly - using attributes or whatever. Now I'm stuck with dates being converted to string (using BsonSerializer). There must be a setting or format one can apply to the dates (eg ISO xxx) to force the BsonSerializer to deserialize JSON date objects into the Bson document instead of strings?